# Is there really a mermaid shrine in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have heard rumors that on the 15th of the last seed near the serpant stone a black goat appears and if you follow it, it leads you to the mermaid shrine. My question is, is all of that true?

Comment: I've heard that you need to be Level 81 or higher to actually see the shrine. <sub>...But as far as I'm concerned it is a myth</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, [that's a hoax](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615803-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/64038315). Not a very good one either.

Further evidence is that the obsessively-detailed coverage of Skyrim in the UESP [doesn't mention "mermaid" once](http://www.uesp.net/w/index.php?title=Special%3ASearch&profile=advanced&search=Mermaid&fulltext=Search&ns134=1&ns146=1&ns142=1&ns0=1&ns118=1&ns120=1&redirs=1&profile=advanced).

Comment: oh ok then i did not know and thanks.